# SOQL query giving error - illegal assignment from List to List

Tags: soql

```
trigger AccountCallableContact on Account (before insert) {
    for (Account acct : Trigger.new) {
        if (acct.Phone != Null) {
            LIST<Contact> MatchContact = [SELECT AccountId,
                                          COUNT(Id)
                                          FROM Contact
                                          WHERE Id = :acct.Id
                                          AND Phone != NULL
                                          GROUP BY AccountId];
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

The GROUP BY makes the SOQL an aggregate query and the result must be a `List<AggregateResult>`

See [Apex doc on Aggregate queries](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_agg_fns.htm?search_text=aggregateresult)

That said, your trigger is not bulkified as you are doing SOQL inside of a for loop. See [Trailhead on how to avoid this](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_triggers/apex_triggers_bulk)

Comment: There's at least 3 other problems with this code, too.

Comment: ah yes -- before insert trigger referencing acct.Id being notable